# OpenCart - "Invalid Token Session" error - how to fix now & prevent in the future?

Tags: php, session, opencart, token

OpenCart 2.0.3.1

Problem #1: in Admin, trying to edit multiple items in multiple tabs usually results in error message "invalid token session, please login again".

Problem #2: this error message seems to happen at random intervals; I can't seem to determine the "timeout".

Problem #3: the error message appears AFTER clicking "Save", meaning all the changes are LOST. I have many tabs open with intricate changes, and I would like to know if it's possible to somehow "recover" the token session into the URL, so I can actually save them.

Comment: Opencart redirects admin to the login page only when a token and a session token mismatch.

Comment: Agree with Ved Pandya, are you sure that all those tabs you are working with belong to same session? If you re-login in one of the tabs, what you describing will happen.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a vQmod script to keep me logged in while the admin tabs are open. Feel free to use it. :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modification>
    <id>Keep Admin Users Logged In - Opencart 2.x</id>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <vqmver>2.5.1</vqmver>
    <author>Tibor Besze</author>

    <file name="admin/controller/user/user.php">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[class ControllerUserUser extends Controller {]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[
                public function pingUser() {
                    $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
                    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode(1));
                }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file name="admin/controller/common/footer.php">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[return $this->load->view('common/footer.tpl', $data);]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[
                if (isset($this->session->data['token'])) {
                    $data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];
                }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file name="admin/view/template/common/footer.tpl">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[</body>]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[
              <?php if (isset($token)) { ?>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                  setInterval(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "index.php?route=user/user/pingUser&token=<?php echo $token; ?>",
                      dataType: "json",
                      timeout: 10000
                    });
                  }, 15000);
                });
              </script>
              <?php } ?>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```